# ESP8266 cannot reconnect to last saved WiFi network

Tags: esp8266, wifimanager

I'm using WifiManager library to manually add user's network on configuration portal. Already it works fine, but every time I power off and power on again, it does not connect to network I have established previous. To connect I have to pin out the 'Vcc' of ESP8266 and pin in again and then again connect with ESP8266 network and go to configure portal.

For now I have two lines in code with 'WifiManager';
Good news is that connects to Wifi by configurationPortal.

```
ESP8266WebServer server; //server variable
void setup() {
  initializePin(); //call function
  Serial.begin(74880);
  delay(500);

  //Connect to network
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  wifiManager.autoConnect("ESP8266","password");

  Serial.println("Connected.");

  if (!MDNS.begin("esp8266"))   {  Serial.println("Error setting up MDNS responder!");  }
      else                          {  Serial.println("mDNS responder started");  }

serverSection();
server.begin();
Serial.println("Server started");
}
```

I need to connect to previous established network, 
Also it would be fine to run Configuration Portal if there wont be connection to that network ( for example if device would be transfer to other place)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is supposed to connect to the internet. What happens usually when you use auto connect and it fails is that `WL_IDLE_STATUS` occurs. Read more about it here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiStatus . What I would do is to check if I got that status then I would try to reconnect to the wifi with a delay of 2 seconds. Here is an example:

```
if (WiFi.status() == WL_IDLE_STATUS) {
    delay(2000);
    WiFi.begin("yourssid", "password"); 
}
```